# Can we have a Post Install Script for unmanaged package

Tags: apex, deployment

We want to create custom setting/custom object records after unmanaged package installed successfully. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is only available for managed packages.

I don't have a doc handy that says this explicitly, but you'll notice all references to them are in the context of managed packages ([like this one](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=apex_post_install_script.htm&type=0))

I've also personally heard the packaging PM specifically confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

A slight work around for this is to add a class with a static method to the unmanaged package and then run the method anonymously in the developer console post install...

```
public class MyUnmanagedPackagePostInstallScript {

    public static void doSomething() {

        //I do things like create records and dml

    }
}
```

Install the package with the class included and then open the execute anonymous apex window and run:

```
MyUnmanagedPackagePostInstallScript.doSomething();
```